# PHP- How to get last inserted ID from mysqli query inside a class

Tags: php

I know returning the last inserted ID when running a straight query is simple:

```
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO site_stats (PageView) VALUES('1')");

if ($query) {

    $id = $db->insert_id;
    echo 'The ID is: '.$id; 
}
```

However, I am running all of my queries through a class which helps me keep track of how many queries I am executing and how long it's taking. The class is simple and straightforward:

```
class dbLog {

    public $queries = array();

    public function query($sql) {

        global $db;

        $start = microtime(true);
        $query = $db->query($sql);

        $this->queries[] = microtime(true) - $start;
        return $query;
    }

    public function getCount() {
        return sizeof($this->queries);
    }

    public function getTime() { 
        return number_format(array_sum($this->queries), 5);
    }

} // end dbLog class

$dbLog = new dbLog;
```

The problem is, when I run queries through this class, I can not figure out how to return the last inserted ID:

```
$query = $dbLog->query("INSERT INTO site_stats (PageView) VALUES('1')");

    if ($query) {

        $id = $dbLog->insert_id;
        echo 'The ID is: '.$id; // Returns error
    }
```

The error I get returned is `Undefined property: dbLog::$insert_id`

How can I get the ID of the last inserted row?

Comment: `$dbLog->insert_id;` will throw an error because $dbLog is an instance of your class and not an instance of mysqli.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MySQLi insert ids from multi\_query()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902947/php-mysqli-insert-ids-from-multi-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrapping the `mysqli` class in another class (you're also using `global`, which is not ideal)

What you need is a method to get the ID from the actual mysqli instance

```
public function getId() {
    global $db;
    return $db->insert_id;
}
```

If I were you I'd use dependency injection and make your mysqli instance part of the class itself

```
class dbLog {
   /** @var \mysqli */
   protected $db;

   public function __construct(\mysqli $db) {
       $this->db = $db;
   }

   public function query($sql) {
      $start = microtime(true);
      $query = $this->db->query($sql);

      $this->queries[] = microtime(true) - $start;
      return $query;
   }

   public function getId() {
       return $this->db->insert_id;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your class is just using `$db` from the global scope, you can use `$db->insert_id` as you originally did.

To do this in a proper manner you'd want to actually wrap the `$db` object inside your own class / object, either by extending (inheriting) from the original class and then instantiating your own, or by implementing the methods you want to expose through your own class, and giving `$db` to the constructor and keeping the reference internally.